# required back five year data .with weekno ,weekdateformat ,year, financial year

Tags: sql-server

1. required back five year data 
   like weekno  ,weekdateformat ,year, financial year

   2. but required week no always 1 for financial year like

      1,Mar 28 2015 - Apr 03 2016    ,2016-2017  ,2016

/procedure weekyearformat/

```
create PROCEDURE [dbo].[Proc_weekyearformat]
@WeekNum int
, @YearNum int

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET FMTONLY OFF ;
set  @WeekNum=datepart(wk,getdate());
set @YearNum=datepart(yyyy,getdate())
declare  @yearcout int =5;


SELECT *
FROM
 -- once you have the @WeekNum and @YearNum set, the following calculates the date range.
(SELECT datepart(wk,DATEADD(wk,-10,getdate()))
as count1, convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 6, '1/1/' + convert(char,@YearNum)) + 
(@WeekNum-1), 0))+' - '+ 
 convert(varchar(11),DATEADD(wk, DATEDIFF(wk, 5, '1/1/' + convert(char,@YearNum)) + (@WeekNum-1), -1)) 
 as formatset,convert(varchar,@YearNum)+'-'+convert(varchar,@YearNum+1) as yearset,
 convert(varchar,@YearNum) as  yearone
)
AS StartOfWeek;
end 

--exec Proc_weekyearformat 1,2016
```

Comment: please check here  on how to improve question:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: This not desire output i required output of above qurey

Comment: Yes, what is your required output of that stored procedure , for example `@WeekNum = 1`, `@YearNum = 2016` ?

Comment: if you run above procedure it will execute ..as per executable record required back five year data.

Comment: if required more clarity ..plz revert me back